# Photoshop - Round sharp corner edges on shapes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector-graphics

**The problem**

I use Photoshop and have a font (for a logotype) that have very sharp edges. I want to in a simple way round all corners on that font to a radius I set.

I know I can use curves on every corner on every letter but that takes a lot of time.

**What I have done so far**

I have converted the font to a vector shape.

**The solution - maybe**

I'm guessings

1. I can fix it with some action?
2. Maybe I can use a cutter shape in some way?
3. If nothing else works maybe I have to create a pixel flat image, round the corners and then convert it back again?

Comment: Should the result be vector-based or can it be rasterized?

Comment: It's going to be a vector.

Answer (score 3):

This tutorial [Creating Rounded Smooth Edges](http://photoshop-dragon.com/Tutorials/Tips_and_Tricks/Rounded_Edges.htm) describes how to use Gaussian Blur, followed by
contrast adjustment, to arrive at this result :

[image]

Comment: What if it is not a solid color? Besides, the rounded corners *look* like they are blurred instead of just round, and it does not allow for controlling the radius of the curves (the radius of the blur filter is completely unrelated).

Comment: @Synetech: The post asked for text, which is in solid color. The only solution with a radius I can think of is curves, which the poster already discarded as too much work.

Comment: They didn't say it was solid; text can be gradient, texture, etc.

Comment: @Synetech: I agree that this possible, but quiet rare. These cases should be treated with other tools.

Comment: Even with a solid color, it *looks blurred* instead of rounded. Either way, I take it that it doesn't suffice since he started a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

The only easy way out method I can think of to this (As opposed to rounding each corner manually as you described) would be to rasterize the layer, select it's contents (control-leftclick the layer image) and then use "Select -> Modify -> Smooth" with a low value. Once you have a smoothed selection, "Select -> Inverse" and delete. You could also fiddle around with feathering in the same way, assuming the font can have a faded edge.

Good luck, this is all I've got.